# Does Titanium convert iPhone apps to Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I was talking with someone about iPhone and Android apps and they said there was something around called "*Titanium*" that could convert an iPhone app to an Android app and vice versa; being that they are written in different languages (amongst other nuances) I found this a little hard to believe.

I'm assuming he meant [*this*](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)

From what I can understand, you can't "convert" an existing app from one to the other, but if you build an iPhone app based off of this API THEN it can be converted to the other?

Am I right in my thinking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost right. In Titanium you build your app using JavaScript (and HTML/CSS for webviews - sort of webpages) and it converts it to native code for both platforms - Obj C for iOS and Java for Android. However you still need to write a significant amount of platform specific code because not everything will work right out of the box on both platforms. And yes - you can **not** convert existing apps using Titanium to anything.

Comment: *"...need to write a significant amount of platform-specific code..."* is slightly misleading; It depends on what your app needs to do. Some of the `Ti` APIs are implemented well enough to compile into native code on both sides, while others do require platform-specific code to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

The word "convert" is inaccurate in describing what Titanium Mobile does. You don't *"build an iPhone app based off of this API"*, you write your app using the Ti API (which is based in Javascript/HTML/CSS), and when you compile that app you end up with both a native iOS app package and a native Android app package.